# Express Router Delete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mern

I've written a simple "Grocery List" web application using the MERN stack (Mongo, Express, React, Node). The issue that I'm having is that my DELETE REST command is not firing unless I reload the page. Below is the source code for my event handler and the backend.

**Event Handler**

```
handleRemove(e) {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/list/' + e._id, {
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            method: "DELETE",
            body: e
        })
        this.refs.list.forceUpdate();
    }
```

**Express Backend**

```
router.delete('/list' +'/:id',function(req,res) {
        item.remove({
            _id: req.params.id
        }, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PATCH, POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, DELETE");
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                return res.send(err);
            } else {
                console.log("successfully deleted")
            }
        })
    })
```

**OnClick**

```
<button onClick={() =>
          this.props.handleRemove(item)}
          className="item" key={item._id + "btn"}>Remove</button>
```

Link to my repo
https://github.com/ahahn95/GroceryList

Comment: Can you show where you are calling `handleRemove`?

Comment: I added the button with the onClick, I am using an arrow function

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by not firing unless you reload the page? You mean it fires when the page first loads or if you navigate to the page from another route, then the function wont fire and you have to reload?

Comment: I think what you mean is that the item isn't being removed from the page when you click delete, but when you refresh it is.  Therefore, the REST command is being sent, you are just not updating the state, to reflect the changes on the front end.

Comment: @Stretch0 it isn't firing until the page is reloaded. However, from my node/backend terminal window, I noticed that the DELETE isn't showing up until I reload the page either. I have my repo up in the original post if that helps give any clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are calling the `handleRemove` onClick correctly.

If it is firiing on page load then I suspect you are doing this:

```
<button onClick={this.handleRemove()}>Delete</button>
```

When you should be doing this:

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleRemove()}>Delete</button>
```

Comment: Yep, I am using an arrow function. I added that code to my OP.

Answer (score 0):

The `DELETE` command is firing off.  This will not update the UI.

You have to update the `state`.

In `handleRemove`:

```
handleRemove(e) {
  fetch('http://localhost:3001/list/' + e._id, {
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    method: "DELETE",
    body: e
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({items: this.state.items.filter(item => { 
      return item._id !== e._id // change this to match your code if necessary
    })});
    // this.refs.list.forceUpdate(); not sure what this does
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```